# How to put widget oververflows over another widget without using the Stack widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm in a case I can't use the `Stack` widget, I wat to put a widget over another widget.
is there any other way than wrapping them in the `Stack` widget?

share with me your ideas

Comment: Why can't you use a Stack widget? Can you show us some snippets? What about IndexedStack?

Comment: This is a classic example of "I know X is the best way to do this, but what would I do if I couldn't use X" without ever explaining the unspecified constraint preventing the ideal solution.

Comment: Hi, I want  to merge a row with another widget, I mean I want a part of widget overflows on the row, and space of this part affects the other widgets in the tree, but I don't want to use Stack because this will overflow anything inside of it, and will evaluate widgets as layers, If this makes sense